# How to change the path of a jar file imported to a Netbeans project?

Tags: netbeans, javafx, jar

i imported a jfeonix jar file into my Netbeans project while it was in my pen drive. And it worked fine while the pen drive was still plugged on.
When i removed my pen, i cannot build my project and it says that 
**Could not find resource file **

Then i tried copying the jar file to my desktop and then importing it again to the libraries of my project.. It would still give the same error, and the fact i fine surprising is that it still gives the same path as it was inside my pen drive even after i imported the jar file again from the Desktop..

So i was thinking what if i can changed the path to refer the jar file manually from inside the project...

has anyone faced this problem before?
Hope someone can help me with this..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried removing the jar and then trying to add it again from the location of your desktop?

Comment: Remove the jar from the libraries and add it again, but this time be sure to select `Copy to Libraries Folder`...

Comment: @ItachiUchiha yes i did.. but no use... it still gave the same path in my pendrive

Comment: @fabian im sorry where can i find this option? and btw i was thinking whether i have to select 'Relative path' when importing the jar file... im quite new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the answer while doing a lot of things to my project..

apparently it seems that even if we delete the jar file from the library, it somehow is still there. and that's why it gives the same path even if we import the jar file again from a different place.

here's the answer i found, just in case someone faced this
Go to Project Properties in File Menu, there under Libraries u can see all the libraries that were imported..
[image]

like shown in the above picture, the other jar files i imported previously are noted as Broken reference.. So i just removed and it did the magic =D